# Magento 2 Filter product collection by multiple attributes with OR

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, attributes, collection

In Magento 2.3.3, How Can I Filter Product Collection by Multiple Attributes? First attribute SKU needs to check using **"IN"** second attribute is yes/no value. I need to filter collection by **SKU array** OR **custom_attribute**. I have tried few things but it did not return expected results.

```
$collection = $layer->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array("attribute"=>"sku",array('in' => $skus)),
        array("attribute"=>"universal_fitment","eq"=>1)
    )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below.

```
<?php
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$queryp = 'product'; 
$querys  = 'product';
$productCollection->addAttributeToFilter(
      [
       ['attribute' => 'sku', 'in' => array('Product 1','Product 2')],
       ['attribute' => 'custom_atribute', 'in' => array('5,4')]
      ]);

$collection = $productCollection->load();

foreach ($collection as $product){
     echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';
}  

?>
```

and other case

```
<?php 

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$products = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')
            ->getCollection()
            //->addAttributeToFilter('is_old',1)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('sku',array('Product 1','Product 2'))
            ->addAttributeToFilter('custom_atribute', array('in' => '5,4'));

echo "<pre>";
print_r($products->getData());

?>
```

Hope it works!

Comment: Won't this filter work like **AND** operator?

Comment: just tell me which attribute you want and tell me cases so I can do as per that.

Comment: I have an array of sku. I only want those products that are exist in that array with those products that have a custom attribute value. Imagine i have 10 products (1-10 sku) in which 6 and 8 have an custom attribute value. Now i have 1,2,3,4,5 sku in an array so i want products 1-5 and 6,8 by filtering collection.

Comment: ok, I can understand but maybe SKU  multiple checks you need a custom query. let me try.

Comment: @Nayem updated answer please check it